# Use login info passed in JSON format in request from client

Tags: javascript, json, http

I'm trying to use information I passed in a JSON format to the server. How do I access the request body and use that info?

If I `console.log(req.body)`, I get the info like this: 
`{ '{"name":"asd","pass":"asd"}': '' }` and I want to access `user.name` and `user.pass` individually.

Any idea? 
Thanks.

```
    var connect = require('connect');
    var cors = require('cors');
    var http = require('http');
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var express = require('express');

    var corsOpts = { origin: '*' };

    var app = connect();

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

     app.use(cors(corsOpts)).use(function (req, res, next) { 
        console.log(req.method);
        console.log(req.url);
        if(req.url === '/register' && req.method === 'POST')
        {
            console.log(req.body.name);
            console.log(req.body.pass);
                register(req,res);
        }
        else
            if(req.url === '/ranking' && req.method === 'GET')
                ranking(req, res);

      }).listen(8020);

    console.log("Server running on 8020");

    function register(req , res){ //quero informação do post aqui
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        //HERE I WILL USE THE DATA
    }
```

Comment: It seams that your client - that sent the json data - did not correctly build the json string into the body. How do you generate the request. (ajax, jquery, angular, rest tool, ... ??? ) Did the sender add a Content-Type: application:json to the request http header?

Comment: I knew the client was sending the info correctly because it was tested in another server, provided by the professor.

Comment: console.log(body) shows us that, the content was not correct parsed. The stringified JSON object you sent from the client was used as a key for a new created object, the value is empty. The answer below provides a workaround: "reparse the key string into an JSON object". This will work, but it's only an ugly workaround. It would be better to find the cause than to fight the symptoms (Frank'n'Further ;-)). Perhaps it's the order of using the middleware, try to use `bodyparser.json()` before `bodyparser.urlencoded()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will help you understand how to get it

```
var a = { '{"name":"asd","pass":"asd"}': '' };
var h = JSON.parse(Object.keys(a)[0]);
console.log(h.name);
console.log(h.pass);
```

Comment: Yeah, I got it! Thanks, and a happy new year!

Comment: Happy New year to you too !!